# Set Reportlab generated PDF to open in SinglePage Layout?

Tags: django, pdf, reportlab

I created a Django app in which I render a PDF by ReportLab. Everything works fine, so I am working on the refinements.

I think it is common knowledge, that the PDF specifications allow to open a document in a specific layout. I am especially looking for the PageLayout SinglePage. See page 140 in the [Adobe PDF reference, version 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf).

Is there such a functionality in ReportLab? I went through the document for the 3rd time, but I only found "2.6 Other canvas methods" in the [ReportLab User Guide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf). Any hints on how I can add the PageLayout functionality to my canvas or page in ReportLab?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: Guess it isn't possible, the only thing I could locate for you was the `setViewerPreference` function which allows you to set `FitWindow` and `CenterWindow` (8.1 of the PDF ref) which is most cases will produce a similar result I believe.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Good hint. I still cannot get it to work. Maybe that flag is ignored by some readers. I think I accept the fact that this has to be set manually.